# Analyse multiple lines on linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have to make a command (so no script) in linux that only shows 1 part of a .txt file. I already searched the man pages of grep and sed, but they only analyse one line at a time (if i'm not mistaking), so that's not what i want.

The start and end of the part of the file I have to show are marked like this:

```
*** START OF... ***
...
*** END OF... ***
```

I can't use the head and tail commands since I'm not suppose to know where exactly these lines are in the file.

Comment: What do you mean "make a command (so no script)"? And why can't you use a script? Is this some homework assignment? You might use `awk`, which again goes line by line, but you can keep track of the contents and only start working with the input once you reach the trigger `*** START OF... ***` line.

Comment: It's just an exercise that I'm making, and it says that you should use commands (we hadn't seen scripting when we got this exercise). We never saw how awk works so it should go without awk, it can be that on the examn itself, they say that you can't use awk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -ne '/START OF/,/END OF/p' << EOF
> 2 3 5
> 3 4 7
> *** START OF ... ***
> 1 2 3
> 2 3 5
> 3 4 7
> 4 5 9
> *** END OF ... ***
> 2 3 5
> 3 4 7
> EOF
*** START OF ... ***
1 2 3
2 3 5
3 4 7
4 5 9
*** END OF ... ***
```

EOF is here doc, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) for more info. `-e` indicate that the next argument would be treated as command other than filename.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But can you explain a little bit? I understand everything except the EOF part (or is this just the filename) and why you need the -e flag. I now it has something to do with a script, but I don't really understand it.